# ¿Cómo ordenar un arreglo de números en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Me encontré con este simple problema en `javascript`, al realizar un `sort` a un `array` de números no me los ordenaba correctamente de menor a mayor:

```js
var arrayStrings = ['Banana', 'World', 'Apple', 'Chocolate']
var arrayNumbers = [10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 78, 23]

console.log(arrayStrings.sort()) // Lo ordena bien
console.log(arrayNumbers.sort()) // Lo ordena mal
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar de esta forma:

```js
var arrayNumbers = [10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 78, 23]

// Sintaxis ES5
console.log(arrayNumbers.sort(function (a, b){
    return a - b;
}))

// Sintaxis ES2015
console.log(arrayNumbers.sort((a, b) => a - b ))
```

También se puede de hacer de una manera implicita realizando un `prototype` de la siguiente forma:

```js
var arrayNumbers = [10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 78, 23]

Array.prototype.sortNumbers = function(){
    return this.sort(
        function(a,b){
            return a - b
        }
    );
}

console.log(arrayNumbers.sortNumbers())
```

Comment: Utiliza la primera forma, usando ES2015. [No es conveniente](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) tocar el prototipo de objetos nativos del lengaje.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que los programadores en general os complicáis la vida de mala manera. La cosa es mucho más simple.

```js
function comparar(a,b){return a - b}

ejemplo=new Array(10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 78, 23)

function ordenar(){

  ejemplo1=ejemplo.sort(comparar)

  alert('el orden de los números es  ' + ejemplo1[0] + '-' + ejemplo1[1] + '-' + ejemplo1[2] + '-' + ejemplo1[3] + '-' + ejemplo1[4] + '-' + ejemplo1[5] + '-' + ejemplo1[6]);
}

//Llamando a la función ordenar() aparecería una cuadro emergente con el texto "el orden de los números es 3-5-8-9-10-23-78"

ordenar();
```

Comment: Me llama la atención que te excluyas del comentario: ***Creo que los programadores en general os complicáis la vida de mala manera***. Sin embargo tienes razón en que muchas veces nos complicamos demasiado. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayNumbers = [10, 8, 9, 5, 3, 78, 23];

var orden = arrayNumbers.sort((a,b)=>{
    return a-b;
 }); 
console.log(orden);
```

Es el mismo metodo solo que haces la comparacion de cual es menor y cambia

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero esto ya se menciona en las demás respuestas, puedes agregar una respuesta que de otras opciones para resolver el problema. Revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Además, revisa [answer].